# IOS, Local notification in app - not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, notifications

I make some checks and then fire it, but its work only when the app is in the background.

How can I fire notification when the user is in the app?

I am using the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method but its response only in the background and not in the app. I also tried to fire a notification in 
the viewDidLoad method but it didn't work either.

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application
  didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
        fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
                UILocalNotification* n1 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
                n1.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1];
                n1.alertBody = @“test”;
                n1.soundName = @"default";
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification: n1];

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

Comment: you could handle local notification in - application:didReceiveLocalNotification:

Comment: Hi, my problem is not to handle the notification him self, my problem is that the notification is not fired when the app is running ..

Comment: If the app is running while the notification is delivered, there is no alert displayed on screen. The application automatically calls its delegate’s application:didReceiveLocalNotification: method. See [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-local-notification-tutorial/)

Comment: just handle the application state is running to show alter by yourself. just like this:  if (UIApplicationStateActive == application.applicationState){ // do your alert for yourself}

Answer (score 0):

`UILocalNotification` are designed to be fired when user is not using the application as per `UILocalNotification` say here in the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/)

if you want to know if the application has received an `UILocalNotification` you may use following code.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
if ([notification.alertBody isEqualToString:@"Application is timeout!"])
   {
     // show an alert regarding your notification
   }
}
```